# Documentation for the animate package with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, documentation, animate

I'm trying to locate some detailed documentation on the [`animate`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/animate) package. When I look at examples here and in other places, there is really way too much unknown syntax to figure out. I was hoping someone here could help. I have started using TikZ a couple of months ago and wanted to try my luck with animating some examples, but mostly I find fairly complex examples that others have created and I need to start off with something a little more basic. I've also searched online, but it just seems as though there is a missing manual somewhere. I have the official documentation by the way.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) [This](http://www.tn-home.de/TUGDD/Stuff/AGlanceAtAnimate.pdf) might help.

Comment: As first step you can look for Q/A in the [tag:animate] and [tag:animation] tags here. Notice also that usually, to animate a TikZ picture, not always is needed the `animate` package: very often you can rely on the TikZ style `visible on` from [Daniel](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55849/13304) and [a bunch of other styles](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84608/13304). A couple of examples are [1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85914/13304) and [2](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88042/13304).

Comment: The package manual is good, though it took me a couple of times through it before I knew what was going on.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: Are you assuming OP is using beamer as well as TikZ?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: ops... you're perfectly right: that's a big assumption. To rectify the previous comment: the styles I was mentioning should be used within Beamer presentations.

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73067/how-to-use-autoplay-within-animate-package-together-with-a-pause-at-the-end-of/73093#73093 I give a complete (short) example of the animate package by frames made in TikZ.

Comment: First, thank you all for your suggestions and I will explore all of them. I was aware that you can animate within Beamer without the animate package. Sorry for taking so long to get back, but I posted this question right before I had to pick up my 2 year old. Thanks again. I'm sure I'll be back with some more questions, and hopefully with greater detail.

Comment: If you happen to speak french, another nice tutorial is on [MathemaTeX](http://wiki.mathematex.net/doku.php?id=wiki:latex:modules:animate).

Comment: @zeroth: I just finished reading your tutorial of the timeline which I like a lot. You presented it in a much easier way to understand, at least, for me. Is there a name for the programming syntax? I hear references to lua, but there really should be a manual or something out there because when I look at one persons example and then another i notice certain syntax that i've not seen before which implies that they learned of it somewhere specifically on the texample.net . Thanks again.

Comment: @AlexG I don't speak french, but google chrome does a pretty good job of translating it, so thank you for the link.

Answer (score 4):

*Collecting information from comments:*

- The package does contain an own documentation, available on all important TeX distributions.
- User zeroth provided an answer in TeX.SX with a complete example: [How to use autoplay (within animate package) together with a pause at the end of every playing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73093/).
- A presentation by Tobias Nähring: [A Glance at Animate](http://www.tn-home.de/TUGDD/Stuff/AGlanceAtAnimate.pdf) (PDF file).
- A tutorial for people who understand French or know, how to use an on-line translator: [MathemaTeX – animate](http://wiki.mathematex.net/doku.php?id=wiki:latex:modules:animate).