# Package animate is great but could it have a better animation compression?

Tags: beamer, pdftex, animations, animate, gif

I just tried the `animate` package to get pdf files with animations and it works great!

However, I noticed that the size of the files generated is 10 times larger that what it could be for the animations that I am dealing with, and for most cases it is even worse.

I believe that the reason is not using the difference between consecutive frames instead of the full frame for every frame.
This is for example what gifsicle uses http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/  (source available)
"Stores only the changed portion of each frame, and can radically shrink your GIFs."

Any chance this could be optimized in the `animate` package?

Comment: I think you should take a look at my answer in: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73067/how-to-use-autoplay-within-animate-package-together-with-a-pause-at-the-end-of it addresses your exact proposition. By the way, it would be very difficult for the package to automatically determine equivalent code segments as. So I think this will be very hard to achieve. The only think I can think of is generation all pdf's without compression, then remove all duplicate objects, and then compress... But... So the answer would be, yes it can be optimized in `animate`, but only manually.

Comment: I think PDF is not a good format for these type of improvements. It's just a document not a container after all.

Comment: @zeroth I guess the OP wants to animate bitmap sequences and optimize the PDF file size by using differential bitmaps, as `gifsicle` does. We *can* use `gifsicle` for producing a size-optimzed bitmap sequence to be used here. And the timeline feature is needed, as in your answer; thanks for the link!

Comment: @AlexG yes, that is probably the essence. And of course generating the bitmaps via gifsicle seems like the way to go! :) Great.

Answer (score 11):

You can optimize the PDF animation for size using differential bitmaps and the `timeline` feature of the `animate` package.

Note however, that with every new animation frame to be shown the number of  differential frames that needs to be re-displayed increases by one. This may slow down a running animation as time advances. Adobe Reader was not primarily optimized for graphical rendering speed. For long bitmap sequences, it may therefore be better to produce a video file (MP4/H.264) and embed this one with the `media9` package.

If you still want to animate differential bitmap sequences, proceed as follows:

(1) Create a size optimized version of the original animated gif using `gifsicle`:

```
gifsicle -O3 animated.gif > optimized.gif
```

For testing purposes you could try this animated gif from the asymptote web site: http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/gallery/animations/wheel.gif

(2) Produce a PNG sequence (`difference-0.png`, `difference-1.png`, ...) of image differences, using the the `ungif.sh` script listed below. The script writes the timeline to be used with `\animategraphics` to standard output which is redirected into the text file `timeline.txt`:

```
ungif.sh optimized.gif difference.png > timeline.txt
```

(3) The PDF with the animated sequence can be produced from the following LaTeX source file (The max. frame number and perhaps the frame rate will need to be adjusted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}

\noindent\animategraphics[
  controls,
  width=0.5\linewidth,
  timeline=timeline.txt
]{10}{difference-}{0}{99} %adjust the maximum frame number

\end{document}
```

(4) Before viewing the animation in Adobe Reader, make sure that 'Smooth images' in the Reader settings (Edit->Preferences->Page Display) is un-checked. Otherwise you get ugly artifacts.

Contents of Bash script `ungif.sh` (requires ImageMagick):

```
#!/bin/bash

wxh=$(identify -format '%Wx%H' $1[0])
fs=$(identify -format %n $1)

for (( i=0; i<$fs; i++ ))
do
  convert -page $wxh ${1}[$i] -matte -background none -layers coalesce -quality 90 ${2/./-$i.}
  echo "::${i}x0"
done
```

Comment: Thank You so much for your clear explanation / description on how to proceed. I create a PDF file 50% smaller but as you pointed out it is too slow and gets slower as the frame count increases. I would like to explore how to generate a video file (MP4/H.264) and embed it with the media9 package (as you suggested above). I hope there is a compression method that keeps the lines sharp without blurring/aliasing/etc for animations such as http://www.geogebra.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=25044&p=88364&hilit=animated+gif#p88364  any advice will be appreciated. Thanks again for your help !!!

Comment: @CarlBaum: Firstly, I'd try to export the frames as vectorial graphics files in either EPS or PDF formats (depending on whether `latex` or `pdflatex` is used) from within GeoGebra, and animate those with `\animategraphics`. With vectorial graphics files, text and lines are kept sharp at any magnification and frame rates of 12 FPS should be possible.

Comment: @CarlBaum: If you want to create and embed a video (AdobeReader on Win or OSX required for viewing), proceed as follows: (1) `gifsicle --unoptimize orig.gif > unopt.gif` (2) `convert unopt.gif frame.png` (3) video at 12 FPS: `ffmpeg -i frame-%d.png -vf scale="trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" -vcodec libx264 -x264opts keyint=12 -r12 myvideo.mp4` (4) Go to http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47116 for how to embed `myvideo.mp4` using the `media9` package.

Comment: Alex, Thanks You so much for the instructions. I was able to generate the mp4 and then a pdf without any problems. In my case the size reduction was 1/4 compared with the animate approach, but also the resolution is lower (perhaps half?) which would lead to a 1/4 size ratio. It was good because I learned to include .mp4/etc, but for animated GIF files I will stick with the animate package for resolution, better resizing quality, and also has the controls. After non using latex for many years, I find that these tools have become very sophisticated !!!! Thank You !!!

Comment: @CarlBaum: As for size, you can arbitrarily scale your video (`\includemedia` of `media9`) or animation (`\animategraphics`) via `width` and `height` options of these commands. Video resolution depends on the tool you are using. With `ffmpeg`, using the command line in my previous comment, the resolution is the same as of the input PNG sequence. In case you want to stick with the `animate` approach, consider animating vector graphics rather than bitmaps. You will probably get smaller files, better quality and higher frame rates. Look for PDF or EPS export in GeoGebra.