# How to moves two or more parallel images towards to meet at a fixed position in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, overlays, animations

Suppose I have four images in a horizontal line. I would like to super impose some of the images( suppose Share0 and Share2) in the second row at the fixed position. It should look like moving style. I can do it with animation in powerpoint. How can I do it in beamer?

[image]

I have tried to do this using the following code but failed:

```
 \begin{frame}{series of images}
 \begin{center}
 \begin{overprint}

 \only<2>{\includegraphics[scale=0.40]{image1.pdf}}
 \hspace{-0.17em}\only<3>{\includegraphics[scale=0.40]{image2.pdf}}
  \hspace{-0.34em}\only<4>{\includegraphics[scale=0.40]{image3.pdf}}
   \hspace{-0.17em}\only<5>{\includegraphics[scale=0.40]{image4.pdf}}

   \only<2-5>{\mbox{\structure{Figure:} something}}

  \end{overprint}
   \end{center}
   \end{frame}
```

Comment: maybe look into the animate package https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73067/how-to-use-autoplay-within-animate-package-together-with-a-pause-at-the-end-of

Comment: @Samcarter can you give an example ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example for a manual animation of the image movement:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\transduration<0-30>{0.1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\foreach \x in{0,...,30}{    
  \node[] at (1.5+0.1333333*\x,2.-0.2*\x) {\includegraphics<+>[width=3cm]{example-image}};
  \node[] at (5.5,2.) {\includegraphics<.>[width=3cm]{example-image-b}};
  \node[] at (9.5-0.1333333*\x,2.-0.2*\x) {\includegraphics<.>[width=3cm]{example-image-a}};
}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]