# How to view smooth animations from beamer

Tags: beamer, animations

In the answer to the question posed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366828/how-to-moves-two-or-more-parallel-images-towards-to-meet-at-a-fixed-position-in/366884#366884), we can see the output of the two figures moving. This might be a basic question, but how is that person showing that output? I am using overleaf, and if I download the PDF, it never shows the animation moving smoothly; it just shows each tiny change as a separate static slide.

My question is, what is the output file that I would need to download to see that smooth animation, and is there a program I need to open the resulting output file so that I can see the smooth animations?

Comment: They converted the set of output slides (30 of them) into a single, animated GIF (using something like ImageMagick) and uploaded it as an image to the site. The original output still remains as a 30-slide [`beamer`](//ctan.org/pkg/beamer) presentation.

Comment: @Werner Thanks. Is there not a simpler way though to code it so that the entire animation appears on just one pdf slide and 30 are not created?

Comment: because it would be really inconvenient to have to make those gifs everytime

Comment: Try package [`animate`](https://ctan.org/pkg/animate/).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `animate`-based version of the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/366884) to the linked [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/366884) with the animation embedded in a single slide. Open PDF in AR or Okular:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{xsavebox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\xsbox{A}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}}%
\xsbox{B}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}}%
\xsbox{C}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-c}}%
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop,width=\linewidth]{10}
\multiframe{31}{i=0+1}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \useasboundingbox
      node[] at (1.5,2) {\phantom{\theA}}
      node[] at (9.5,2) {\phantom{\theC}}
      node[] at (1.5+0.1333333*30,2.-0.2*30) {\phantom{\theA}};
    \node[] at (1.5+0.1333333*\i,2.-0.2*\i) {\theA};
    \node[] at (5.5,2.) {\theB};
    \node[] at (9.5-0.1333333*\i,2.-0.2*\i) {\theC};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{animateinline}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```